# Use random theme

Tags: themes

I am thinking about random theme from 2-3 selected themes, which is shown for new user and saved to cookies or ip, to not show other theme for him again. Just show random themes for new users, so I could see witch theme is better performing.

Is it possible to do this kind of a plugin or create a function for a wordpress? I found that plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-ab-theme-split-tests/ but it seems not to be working properly and I need much simpler solution with possibility to choose few themes to spin from. Please help guys.

Comment: The plugin you have referenced allows you to create different templates within the same `Theme`.  The `Theme` is an integral part of Wordpress and not somthing that can be changed 'on the fly', specificlly because the `ABSPATH` constant references the `Theme` directory.  Thus it is your site that has a `Theme` assigned to it, not the visitor.

Comment: Let's assume you can serve random themes without problems, what are you going to measure and how? Why not test one theme for some time, before trying another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying I don't think it's the best of ideas, but in the interest of answering the question...

The general idea is to filter `template`, `option_template`, and `option_stylesheet` in a plugin and return your desired template slug. The rest of the code is just setting and reading the cookie.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPD Theme Switcher
 */

class WPD_Theme_Switcher {

    private $themes = array(
        'twentythirteen',
        'twentyfourteen',
        'twentyfifteen'
    );
    private $current_theme = '';
    private $cookie = 'wpd_theme_switcher_cookie';

    function __construct() {

        if( empty( $this->current_theme ) && !isset( $_COOKIE[ $this->cookie ] ) ) {
            $this->current_theme = $this->themes[ array_rand( $this->themes ) ];
            setcookie( $this->cookie, $this->current_theme, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) );
        } else {
            $this->current_theme = $_COOKIE[ $this->cookie ];
        }

        // don't switch themes for admin requests
        if( ! is_admin() ){
            add_filter( 'template', array( $this, 'theme_switcher' ) );
            add_filter( 'option_template', array( $this, 'theme_switcher' ) );
            add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', array( $this, 'theme_switcher' ) );
        }

    }

    function theme_switcher(){
        return $this->current_theme;
    }

}
new WPD_Theme_Switcher();
```